# Better Excel Formula for Complex Lookup

Tags: excel-2007, excel-formula

I am trying to improve a complex lookup procedure that I have inherited. The lookup was being generated through several UDF combined with some standard worksheet functions. However, the issue was that when the user updated some data in the source sheet, the re-calc time was unacceptable.

So, I took a look and thought I may be able to write a better Excel formula only solution. Well, I did find a solution, but it is too much for Excel to handle on large data sets, and it crashes (understandably so!) when my VBA runs the formulas against the dataset.

Now, I could implement this in VBA fully, but then the user would have to press a button or something to update after every change. What I would like is a more simpler approach, if there is one, using some of the advanced Excel 2007 formulas. Since I am not as well-versed on those formulas, I am reaching out for some help!

Okay, here is what I have to work with.

**SourceSheet**

Tid's, Settlement Dates, and month-end prices (layer periods identified by 1,2,3, etc) in columns like below

```
Tid   SettleDate   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  ...   n
```

**FormulaSheet**

Amongst other columns, I have the following columns

```
InitLayer   LiqdLayer   InstrClass   Tid   SettleDate   InitPrice   LiqdPrice   Position
```

I also have the layer numbers in columns to the right of the entire data set, like this:

```
1   2   3   4   5   ...   n
```

What I need to do is fill in the proper price changes in these columns based on some logic in the dataset by looking up the prices on the source sheet.

In psuedo-formula, this is what I need to happen for each layer column in the FormulaSheet

```
If Layer < InitLayer OR Layer > LiqdLayer Then Return "-"

ElseIf Layer = InitLayer Then (Layered Price - InitPrice) * Position

     where Layered Price is obtained by finding the Intersect of the LayerNumber 
     Column and Tid Row in the SourceSheet

ElseIf Layer = LiqdLayer Then Previous Layered Price * Position

     where Previous Layered Price is obtained by finding the Intersect of the Previous   
     LayerNumber Column and Tid Row in the SourceSheet

Else (LayeredPrice - Previous Layered Price) * 6

     where Layered Price and Previous Layered Price are defined as above

End If
```

I did come up with this formula, which works well on small data sets, but its **toooooooooo** big and nasty for large data sets, or just too big and nasty period!

```
=IF(OR(CH$3<$AT6,CH$3>$AU6),"-",IF($AT6=CH$3,(HLOOKUP(CH$3,layered_prices,RIGHT(ADDRESS(MATCH(IF($AX6="CUR",$T6 & " " & $G6,$T6),IF($AX6="CUR",layered_curtid,layered_tid),1),1,4),LEN(ADDRESS(MATCH(IF($AX6="CUR",$T6 & " " & $G6,$T6),IF($AX6="CUR",layered_curtid,layered_tid),1),1,4))-1)-1,FALSE)-$AV6)*$C6,IF($AU6=CH$3,($AW6-HLOOKUP(CG$3,layered_prices,RIGHT(ADDRESS(MATCH(IF($AX6="CUR",$T6 & " " & $G6,$T6),IF($AX6="CUR",layered_curtid,layered_tid),1),1,4),LEN(ADDRESS(MATCH(IF($AX6="CUR",$T6 & " " & $G6,$T6),IF($AX6="CUR",layered_curtid,layered_tid),1),1,4))-1)-1,FALSE))*$C6,(HLOOKUP(CH$3,layered_prices,RIGHT(ADDRESS(MATCH(IF($AX6="CUR",$T6 & " " & $G6,$T6),IF($AX6="CUR",layered_curtid,layered_tid),1),1,4),LEN(ADDRESS(MATCH(IF($AX6="CUR",$T6 & " " & $G6,$T6),IF($AX6="CUR",layered_curtid,layered_tid),1),1,4))-1)-1,FALSE)-HLOOKUP(CG$3,layered_prices,RIGHT(ADDRESS(MATCH(IF($AX6="CUR",$T6 & " " & $G6,$T6),IF($AX6="CUR",layered_curtid,layered_tid),1),1,4),LEN(ADDRESS(MATCH(IF($AX6="CUR",$T6 & " " & $G6,$T6),IF($AX6="CUR",layered_curtid,layered_tid),1),1,4))-1)-1,FALSE))*$C6)))
```

**Formula Key**

```
CH = Layer Number
CG = Previous Layer Number
AT = InitLayer
AU = LiqdLayer
AX = InstrClass (used to find a separate lookup for Currencies)
T = Tid
G = SettleDate (used to find a separate lookup for Currencies)
AV = InitPrice
AW = LiqPrice
C = Position
layered_prices = named range for the range of prices under the layer columns in SourceSheet
layered_tid = named range for tid rows in SourceSheet
layered_curtid = named range for currency tid rows in Source Sheet (just a separte lookup if InstrType = Currency, formula the same
```

Are there any other formulas, or combination of formulas that will allow me to get what I am seeking in a more efficient manner than the monstrosity I have created?

Comment: How big is the dataset? If it's over 200k rows it might not feasible as a formula...

Comment: while we might hit that number on some small amount of cases, most will not reach that. I have been exploring the lookup and reference section and I may be onto something... will post if I find a better answer.

Comment: It's hard to visualise the problem, is it possible to post/link to a small amount of example data/.

Comment: will try to do a bit later...  besides wikisend, do you know other dropbox places I can post sample files? My work security is pretty tight, so I can't access a lot of things.

Comment: http://justpaste.it/ can be used to paste direct from/to Excel, used this myself a few times.

Comment: If you decide to go for a VBA solution, one option is to set your macro to detect when the input cells are modified and run automatically. That would avoid any extra user interaction.

In the meantime, please post a sample spreadsheet with some dummy data.

Comment: IMHO, ***user would have to press a button or something to update after every change*** is the reason VBA is running faster. If you process the request upon sheet change, user might get the more annoying lagging UI. My suggestion without VBA is to turn off auto calculation and do a manual refresh only when necessary (eg. before save workbook).

Comment: in my experience index(match()) cuts a pretty significant amount of time off of VLOOKUP and HLOOKUP, i have no idea if it would make a big enough dent for you though

Comment: I usually find it easier to break long formulas like this over several columns. This achieves two things, it makes it easier to step through the formula and often lets you reuse conditions instead of repeating them. You will benefit in this case because your formula seems to repeat the same hlookup in several places. It might be worth a try to split it up it probably run quicker. As mentioned above lookups hog memory and if possible their use should be limited. Could you rearrange your formula to use these functions less?

Comment: I agree with @Kharoof. Start with a pseudo formula and create a field for each chunk of that. Pretend the names you gave in the pseudo formula refers to named fields in a table and then go build those fields. You could have your final formula look almost exactly like your example. `=IF(OR(Layer<InitLayer,Layer>LiqdLayer),"-", IF(Layer=InitLayer,(LayeredPrice-InitPrice)*Position, IF(Layer=LiqdLayer,PreviousLayeredPrice*Position,(LayeredPrice-PreviousLayeredPrice)*6)))`

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Kharoof's comment. You should break this formula into several columns. From my count, you need 4 more columns. The benefits are two-fold: 1) Your formula gets much shorter because you're not repeating the same function over and over and 2) You save memory because Excel will calculate it once instead of several times.

For instance, you call the exact same `ADDRESS` function four times. Excel doesn't "remember" what it was when evaluating a formula and so it calculates it anew each time. If you put it in it's own cell, then Excel will evaluate the cell before any cells that depend on it and store it as a value instead of the formula. When other cells reference it, Excel will provide the pre-evaluated result.

---

First, here's what your final formula should be: (The names in [brackets] indicate that a helper column fits there. It'll be some cell reference like `CI$3` but I wasn't sure where you'd want to put it. You'll have to update those references based on where you add these columns.)

```
=IF(OR(CH$3<$AT6,CH$3>$AU6),"-",IF($AT6=CH$3,([LayerNumber]-$AV6)*$C6,IF($AU6=CH$3,($AW6-[PreviousLayerNumber])*$C6,([LayerNumber]-[PreviousLayerNumber])*$C6)))
```

And here are the four helper columns:

```
[ADDRESS] = ADDRESS(MATCH(IF($AX6="CUR",$T6 & " " & $G6,$T6),IF($AX6="CUR",layered_curtid,layered_tid),1),1,4)
[RIGHT] = RIGHT([ADDRESS],LEN([ADDRESS])-1)
[LayerNumber] = HLOOKUP(CH$3,layered_prices,[RIGHT]-1,FALSE)
[PreviousLayerNumber] = HLOOKUP(CG$3,layered_prices,[RIGHT]-1,FALSE)
```

By splitting it up, each step of the formula is easier to follow / debug as well as faster to process for Excel. If you want some quantitative improvement, the five formulas combined will be around 70% shorter than the single formula you have right now.